# django.db aggregation across multiple fields

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a table like so:

```
ID state  A    B    C
----------------------
1   MD    x    x    x

2   MD    x    x    x

3   WA    x    x    x

4   KY    x    x    x
```

I would like to filter by state, and return the sum of B and C. I can get the sums for B or C individually like so:

```
Table.objects.filter(state=MD).aggregate(x=Sum('B'))
```

I can get the data for B and C like so:

```
Table.objects.filter(state=MD).values('B', 'C')
```

I'm looking for a way to combine the two operations without resorting to raw SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not precisely what I wanted but close:

```
sum(Tables.objects.filter(state=MD).aggregate(x=Sum('B'), y=Sum('C')).values())
```

Comment: Is your answer able to cover for NoneType objects?